# How does H1B role change works?

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, h1-visa

I am in United States on H1B Visa on a "Computer Programmer" role. If I change my role to something other than Computer programmer when my H1B goes into extension than do I need to go for LCA only or I have to go for Petition Amendment?

Also, will the role change affect my salary in any way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to file an amendment when the candidate’s job title changes or gets a promotion, with no significant change in the employee’s job responsibilities.Reference: see [this link](http://www.h1bwiki.com/h-1b-amendment-requirements/)

Comment: Thanks..So does it mean that the salary will also be changed

Comment: @RomilN I think the salary is determined primarily by your employer, not the government.

Comment: Correct..So how can I know if my salary is going to increase or decrease?

Comment: @RomilN ask your employer.